# xsl different behaviour for a literal and a variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

This is a part of my template: 
`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(469802.00*30.05, '#.00')"/>`
When used, it yields a 14117550.10.

However, when i first store the product in a vairable and apply `format-number` afterwards:
    `<xsl:variable name="end">
    <xsl:value-of select="469802.00*30.05"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($end, '#.00')"/>`
 the result is nAn

I use XALAN.

Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code, except its horrifying inefficiency. Multiplying two numbers, converting the result to a text node, making the text node part of a result tree fragment, then getting the string value of the result tree fragment and converting it to a number so you can format it as a string - what are you playing at?

Comment: So what's the proper way to store a number in a variable?

Comment: i simplified the original version, which contained a number of conditions and multiplied parts of the tree, not just numbers (like, set this variable to that if..., set this variable to that if...)

Answer (score 0):

**I can't repro the problem with Saxon.**

**Try**:

```
<xsl:variable name="end" select="469802.00*30.05"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number($end), '#.00')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Xalan to hand, but from your code, I'm wondering if it's something to do with the spaces either side of the `<xsl:value-of>` element within the `<xsl:variable>` element.

Try making sure there's no whitespace inside your `<xsl:variable>` element within the stylesheet.